# Vector out of bounds when assign a vector to a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I've typedefined a vector of integers with name List.

`newList` is of type vector of List.

`oldList` is of type List.

```
newList[m][n] = oldList[i];
```

And I've tried

```
newList[m].push_back(oldList[i]);
```

I dont have much experience with C++ so any help would be nice.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Please provide [mcve], instead of describing your code.

Comment: My crystal ball says you have not resized your vector, so you are accessing it out of range. Impossible to tell for sure without seeing your code.

Comment: @JakeFreeman the only line I used it so far is newList[0][0] = oldList[0]. newList is empty, oldList has a bunch of integers.

Comment: What is the type of oldList

Comment: And does newList been resized to include 0, 0

Comment: @JakeFreeman I did resize the vector and now it works fine ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to resize newList to include the indexes your accessing.